# Chrome DevTools network + some extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to use the network tab from the Chrome DevTools with some Chrome extension? I've tried with some of them and nothing new appeared in the network tab.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the documentation about [Extending Devtools](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools) where it is an extension to the Chrome Devtools to **get information about network requests**, new UI panels and sidebars and interact with inspected page.

Here are the extension APIs that you can use:

- `devtools.inspectedWindow`
- [`devtools.network`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_network)
- `devtools.panels`

Here are the [Featured DevTools Extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/extensions-gallery).